# HTML making Div editable by clicking on the edit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, edit

I am trying to make both DIV's editable when I click on the edit icon on bottom left. How can I do that?

```
<li class="question" id="question2">

    <div class="question-header curves dense-shadows">

        What color is the sky? 
    </div>
    <div class="question-content dense-shadows">
        <ol type="A">
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a1" name="question2" /> Red</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a2" name="question2" /> Green</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a3" name="question2" /> Blue</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a4" name="question2" /> Brown</li>
        </ol>
        <div style="text-align:right">
            <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/editbutton.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='images/editbuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/editbutton.png'" title="Edit" alt="edit" /></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/deletebutton.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='images/deletebuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/deletebutton.png'" title="Delete" alt="delete"/></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: @putvande That makes the div contenteditable by clicking anywhere. I want it to be editable when I click the edit icon.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
<li class="question" id="question2">
    <div class="question-header curves dense-shadows">
        What color is the sky? 
    </div>
    <div class="question-content dense-shadows">
        <ol type="A">
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a1" name="question2" /> Red</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a2" name="question2" /> Green</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a3" name="question2" /> Blue</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q2a4" name="question2" /> Brown</li>
        </ol>
        <div style="text-align:right">
            <a href="#" class="edit"><span style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/editbutton.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='images/editbuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/editbutton.png'" title="Edit" alt="edit" /></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="delete"><span style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/deletebutton.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='images/deletebuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/deletebutton.png'" title="Delete" alt="delete"/></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

<script>    
$('a.edit').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('.question-header, .question-content').attr('contenteditable','true');
});
</script>
```

Note that I have added `class="edit"` and `class="delete"` to your buttons.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense but for some reason when I click on the button nothing happens. Why might that be?

Comment: You won't see a lot, but if you try clicking on the div and start typing, you should see that it is definitively editable. You could add a CSS style for the `contenteditable` element so it is more clear that you can edit it.

Comment: What browser are you using? And is your page you are working on HTML5?

Comment: could it be because contenteditable was never set to true in the script?

Comment: I am using chrome and yes it's html5

Comment: It should work fine if you just add `contenteditable` but better to set it to 'true'

Answer (score 0):

Well you question is not clear but i will try to guess. If you want to make div editable you can mark it with contenteditable

so to do that replace your code

```
 <a href="#"><span style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/editbutton.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='images/editbuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/editbutton.png'" title="Edit" alt="edit" /></span></a>
```

with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit"><span style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="images/editbutton.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='images/editbuttonhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/editbutton.png'" title="Edit" alt="edit" /></span></a>
```

then add script

```
<script>
    $("a.edit").click(function(){
       $("div.question-content").attr("contenteditable", "true");
    });
    </script>
```

Please note that i have added class to link and replaces HREF

Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/r9HTe/